# What does rpc.pingomatic.com respond with to valid pings?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, curl, blogs

I am confused because weblogs.com shoots back a friendly "thanks for the ping!" bit of XML after a successful ping.

I can't seem to find any documentation on pingomatic API anywhere.

Matt writes that he created one 6 years ago, but there are no links on this page: http://blog.pingomatic.com/2006/01/16/internal-api-complete/

EDIT: I think it might be down to anything but pings from wordpress blogs, but I don't understand how they're doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't. You can no longer ping pingomatic via API. No idea how it allows facebook blogs to do so but oh well!?